# "There is no argument given corresponds to required parameter 'name' of 'Character.Character(string)" in 'Player' class which inherits abstract class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, constructor, abstract-class

I have 2 classes 'Character' which is an abstract class and 'Player' class which derives from that abstract class. I am getting error "There is no argument given corresponds to required parameter 'name' of 'Character.Character(string)". I am unable to understand why base keyword is used in the below program and Player class's constructor should contain the parameter name which will resolve this issue. Please help.

```
public abstract class Character
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    public Character(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}


public class Player : Character
{
    //public Player(string name) : base(name)
    //{

    //}
}
```

Comment: The abstract class has a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors), `public Character(string name)` that requires a parameter, `name`. Since `Player` inherits from the abstract `Character` it's required to pass a value to its base constructor. And that's what the `base` keyword is doing, it's passing `name` to the base class' `constructor`.

Comment: @quaabaam Hi, So Is it mandatory that if derived class inherits an abstract class and it has a constructor, so the derived class is required to pass a value to its base constructor like while implementing interfaces , classes have to mandatorily provide definition for the methods of interfaces?

Comment: It's only like an interface in the sense that it's a 'contract' of the object. It's always mandatory to provide constructor parameters and it doesn't matter if inheritance is being used or not. [A constructor is a special method that is used to initialize objects.](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_constructors.php)